# Syntax Error in INSERT INTO Statement (Error 3134)

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm using MS Access 2013. My current issue is with the following code, I use to log user activity.
Table is called: `tbl-activitylog` and has five columns :

```
id
timestamps
Username
Activity
Additional
```

I checked code many times char after char and don't know what's wrong :(

```
TempVars("UserName").Value = "admin"
Logging("Logon", "system")
Public Sub Logging(Activity, Additional As String)
    Dim sql_code As String
    sql_code = "INSERT INTO tbl-activitylog(Username, Activity, Additional) VALUES('" & TempVars("UserName").Value & "','" & Activity & "','" & Additional & "')"
    Debug.Print sql_code
    CurrentDb.Execute sql_code
End Sub
```

Debug print shows:

```
INSERT INTO tbl-activitylog(Username, Activity, Additional) VALUES('admin','Logon','System')
```

Comment: Try : INSERT INTO [tbl-activitylog]([Username], [Activity], [Additional]) VALUES('admin','Logon','System')

Comment: Use [] for table and field names. And also, more important than that, use parameters instead of such string concatenation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This 3134 error denotes a syntax error in your INSERT statement. As the name of your table contains a dash, you need to enclose it between brackets :

```
INSERT INTO [tbl-activitylog]
    (Username, Activity, Additional)
    VALUES('admin','Logon','System')
```

Generally speaking you may as well enclose all fields and table names, to avoid all risks of clashes with [ms-access reserved words](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/learn-about-access-reserved-words-and-symbols-ae9d9ada-3255-4b12-91a9-f855bdd9c5a2), like :

```
INSERT INTO [tbl-activitylog]
    ([Username], [Activity], [Additional])
    VALUES('admin','Logon','System')
```

Answer (score 1):

Becaus of using "-" you have to do it in this way [tbl-activitylog]

```
sql_code = "INSERT INTO [tbl-activitylog](Username, Activity, Additional) VALUES('" & TempVars("UserName").Value & "','" & Activity & "','" & Additional & "')"
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider a parameterized query, an industry best practice in *any* application layer language running SQL in *any* database. With [QueryDefs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/parameters-collection-dao), you can parameterize queries in MS Access.

Even more MS Access will not allow you to save queries with syntax issues. So, be sure to escape special characters and reserved words with square brackets or backticks.

**SQL** *(save below as a query object)*

```sql
PARAMETERS UsernameParam Text, ActivityParam Text, AdditionalParam Text;
INSERT INTO [tbl-activitylog] ([Username], [Activity], [Additional])
VALUES ([UsernameParam], [ActivityParam], [AdditionalParam])
```

**VBA** *(reference above query and bind values without quotes or concatenation)*

```vb
TempVars("UserName").Value = "admin"
Logging("Logon", "system")

Public Sub Logging(Activity, Additional As String)
    Dim sql_code As String
    Dim qdef As QueryDef

    Set qdef = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("mySavedQuery")

    ' BIND PARAMS
    qdef![UsernameParam] = TempVars("UserName")
    qdef![ActivityParam] = Activity
    qdef![AdditionalParam] = Additional

    qdef.Execute dbFailOnError

    Set qdef = Nothing
End Sub
```